# locality sensitive hashing for spatial data

Tags: mapreduce, locality-sensitive-hash, spatial-data

I would like to find out a Locality Sensitive Hashing algorithm in order to split my spatial data into a number of buckets(reducer tasks). The spatial data are actually trajectories so from my understating of LSH a trajectory will be represented a set of 2d points.

Thanks, 
Adam

Comment: Maybe Ullman's book will help you: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you want a [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree):

"Quadtrees are most often used to partition a two-dimensional space by recursively subdividing it into four quadrants or regions."

You could store the actual points in a quadtree, and define trajectories as lists of indices referencing points in the quadtree.

Comment: I have found a geohashing library which encodes the latlon into a string and vice versa.

Comment: And which one it is? How does it work? Would you mind posting an answer so that other people might solve the same problem?

Comment: This library https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java wrap up the core library that i have used. Am working now on these things. I will answer it in a later stage when i sum up things.

Comment: Fine. I have a strong (hobbyist) interest in these topics ("computational geography", so to say), if you want to chat about it, my e-mail is at my SO profile page!

Comment: i cannot see your email

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna check it, but its heltonbiker at gmail dot com. Thanks for your interest!